# wierd js / canvas issue - code example doesn't work locally

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is the best js graph drawing thing - http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Other/example2.html

It is so impressive, that I wanted to play with it a bit, but after downloading all the files, it isn't working.

So I did put this `html` (with all other files) page on web server (jetty) but still no result:

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/35lhlxd.png]

Opening file with Chrome, with properly added `--allow-file-access-from-file` doesn't fix the issue either

Obviously I am doing something wrong, but I have no idea what, so I will be very grateful for any input.

Comment: Please state exactly what isn't working.

Comment: Please compare example to screen attached by me, and it will be obvious. Looks like nothing is working as it should - nodes are not drawn properly and there isn't any response to mouseclicks with movements of nodes

Comment: A first step would be to look for any errors in the JavaScript console. I'm not familiar with Chrome, but it looks like this could be a starting point: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser's debug console?

Comment: @Brant, I was missing 2 .png files that were mentioned in css, so I have added them, and now I see no errors in console, but still there's no improvement in whole behaviour - graph isn't drawn and it's static only.

Comment: @Andrew I have fixed all the errors in console, but it didn't help anyhow. This proves that `.css' and `.js` files are placed properly. (simple alert from linked js file works good, even from the end of `init()` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow html file provided in .zip download from download page is different than html file downloaded directly from online example page (this one uses **obfuscated** (sic!) javascript file named `jit-yc.js` in place of 'normal' and **WELL DOCUMENTED** `jit.js`:) ).

So, if anyone would like to try JIT (there ins't much competition in good graph drawing tools - http://arborjs.org/ seems the only one)- using official download link is the only valid way ;)